# syntax error, unexpected '',' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Tags: 16.04, server, php, openldap

I install openldap in Ubuntu server (192.168.56.101) as the instructions given in https://www.unixmen.com/install-openldap-in-ubuntu-15-10-and-debian-8/.

Now when I access openldap by using http://192.168.56.101/phpldapadmin/ from the remote system whose ip is 192.168.56.102 then it shows an error as :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '',' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php on line 270

[image: Screen shot of configuration]

How can I open web console of openldap server?

Comment: Please replace your screenshot with the actual config file as a code block.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to uncomment the following lines:

```
$config->custom->appearance['attr_display_order'] = array(

[anything that fits your needs in between]

);
```